# Change a materialized value in a source using the contents of the stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream, alpakka

Alpakka provides a great way to access dozens of different data sources. File oriented sources such as HDFS and FTP sources are delivered as `Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]`. However, HTTP requests via Akka HTTP are delivered as entity streams of `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`. In my use case, I would like to retrieve content from HTTP sources as `Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]` so I can build a unified resource fetcher that works from multiple schemes (hdfs, file, ftp and S3 in this case).

In particular, I would like to convert the `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]` source to 
`Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]` where I am able to calculate the IOResult from the incoming byte stream. There are plenty of methods like `flatMapConcat` and `viaMat` but none seem to be able to extract details from the input stream (such as number of bytes read) or initialise the `IOResult` structure properly. Ideally, I am looking for a method with the following signature that will update the IOResult as the stream comes in.

```
  def matCalc(src: Source[ByteString, Any]) = Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = {
    src.someMatFoldMagic[ByteString, IOResult](IOResult.createSuccessful(0))(m, b) => m.withCount(m.count + b.length))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't recall any existing functionality, which can out of the box do this, but you can use [alsoToMat](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Source.html#alsoToMat-akka.stream.Graph-akka.japi.function.Function2-) (surprisingly didn't find it in akka streams docs, although you can look it in source code documentation & java api) flow function together with [Sink.fold](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Sink/fold.html) to accumulate some value and give it in the very end. eg:

```
def magic(source: Source[Int, Any]): Source[Int, Future[Int]] =
    source.alsoToMat(Sink.fold(0)((acc, _) => acc + 1))((_, f) => f)
```

the thing is that `alsoToMat` combines input mat value with the one provided in `alsoToMat`. at the same time the values produced by source are not affected by the sink in `alsoToMat`:

```
def alsoToMat[Mat2, Mat3](that: Graph[SinkShape[Out], Mat2])(matF: (Mat, Mat2) ⇒ Mat3): ReprMat[Out, Mat3] =
  viaMat(alsoToGraph(that))(matF)
```

it's not that hard to adapt this function to return `IOResult`, which is according to the source code:

```
final case class IOResult(count: Long, status: Try[Done]) { ... }
```

one more last thing which you need to pay attention - you want your source be like:

```
Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]]
```

but if you wan't to carry these mat value till the very end of stream definition, and then do smth based on this future completion, that might be error prone approach. eg, in this example i finish the work based on that future, so the last value will not be processed:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}

object App extends App {

  private implicit val sys: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  private implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  private implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = sys.dispatcher

  val source: Source[Int, Any] = Source((1 to 5).toList)

  def magic(source: Source[Int, Any]): Source[Int, Future[Int]] =
    source.alsoToMat(Sink.fold(0)((acc, _) => acc + 1))((_, f) => f)

  val f = magic(source).throttle(1, 1.second).toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.left).run()
  f.onComplete(t => println(s"f1 completed - $t"))
  Await.ready(f, 5.minutes)


  mat.shutdown()
  sys.terminate()
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using a `Promise` for the materialized value propagation.

```scala
val completion = Promise[IoResult]
val httpWithIoResult = http.mapMaterializedValue(_ => completion.future)
```

What is left now is to complete the `completion` promise when the relevant data becomes available.

Alternative approach would be to drop down to the `GraphStage` API where you get lower level control of materialized value propagation. But even there using `Promises` is often the chosen implementation for materialized value propagation. Take a look at built in operator implementations like [`Ignore`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/ca794861c2c2b90a4f5f7aa186c2d2c0507b7e59/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/fusing/GraphStages.scala#L417).